# How to deal with unevenly spaced time series in python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, time, series, resampling

Good afternoon together,

I want to analyze time series data in python, but I cannot be sure in which interval the data is coming. I would guess it comes every five seconds, but maybe sometimes quicker and sometimes slower (maybe the algorithm didn't record any data for an hour). Is there a general approach how to handle such data?

For example, can I do something like this in the following block? Will it work correctly if the data is less frequent sometimes than 5 seconds or more frequent than 5 seconds?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,1.1,1.100001,2,2.5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

length = len(x)
y = [None] * length
pos = 0
while pos < length:
    y[pos] = x[pos]*x[pos]*x[pos]+4*x[pos]*x[pos]+2*x[pos]+1
    pos = pos + 1

print(x)
print(y)

timeline = pd.to_datetime(x,unit="s")
recv = pd.Series(y,timeline)
recv = recv.resample('5S').interpolate(method='spline', order=2) 
print(recv)
```

The output in this case would be:

```
[0, 1, 1.1, 1.100001, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
[1, 8, 9.371000000000002, 9.3710144300073, 29, 46.625, 70, 137, 236, 373, 554, 785, 1072, 1421, 1838, 2329, 2900, 3557, 4306, 5153, 6104, 7165, 8342, 9641, 11068]
1970-01-01 00:00:00       1.0
1970-01-01 00:00:05     236.0
1970-01-01 00:00:10    1421.0
1970-01-01 00:00:15    4306.0
1970-01-01 00:00:20    9641.0
Freq: 5S, dtype: float64
```

Can someone give me any tips on how to handle such data?
If I group it in 5 seconds blocks and let's say `x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and I use the same source code, then I get an error message. How can I prevent that error message?

Thanks for your help!

As far as I understood, I need to have at least 2* sampling size (in my case 2*5=10 seconds). But I have no idea how to prevent the error and if my approach for upsampling and downsampling simultaneously is even correct.

Comment: Could you specify the error you get, please?

Comment: Seems the error message is: "(m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=2" When I say x = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80] and recv = recv.resample('15S').interpolate(method='spline', order=2), it is okay, if the array goes from 10-90

Comment: Code works fine with `x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`; `recv` then just has two rows. As an aside, your initialization (calculating `y`) is not the subject of the question, but you are aware that `y` could be done in one line, right?